# Catch events using ngrx/store from any components in angular

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

How to use ngrx store to catch events from grand child component in angular without using service, behavior subject or @Output

Comment: I want a standard solution, but without the use of a service or forming a manual pass of events in each component level. I am new to ngrx... Ref link: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ActionsSubject`. This way you can listen to all ngrx actions fired..  assuming that this is what you mean by "ngrx events".

```
 constructor(private store: Store,
          private actionsSubject: ActionsSubject) 
 {
    this.actionsSubject.pipe(filter((action) => {
      // can filter them, if needed
    })).subscribe((action) => {
       console.log('action', action);
       // do something with it
    });
 }
```